# How to make a Speech API with Java

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech-synthesis, javax.speech

I would like to know the steps in making a java speech recognizer/API WITHOUT using sphinx or anything else. I want to build from the ground up!!! Also a Text to speech from the ground up. 100% my own. I know it's going to be a lot of work. I just want to know.

Comment: And what have you found so far from your own research?

Comment: Everything says use sphinx but I want my own thing I want to know how

Comment: This require advanced math and programming knowledge. And even with those, this will not be an easy task. Anyway, I suggest that you go through the research section of the Sphinx project: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/research/

Comment: "I want to know how".  That is what your own research should help you find out.

Answer (score 4):

First you want your sound-input as bytestream, how to do so is explained by oracle:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html
Next, you write the logic and algorithms to analyze and process the byte stream.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition#Algorithms
Good luck.